# How do "we" get a custom warning when asking a question on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, tag-warnings

When I ask a question on Stack Overflow with the tag of `regex`, Stack Overflow greets me with this custom warning:

[image]

I'd love to create one of these for the `pandas` tag.  I'm assuming this is a feature that generalizes across all exchange sites.

Is there an API, or protocol to get this same behavior for another tag?

If not, can we get one?