# How effective are tag warnings?

Tags: discussion, tag-warnings

[tag-warnings](/questions/tagged/tag-warnings) intend to warn users when they use certain tags.

Is there any data on how effective those tag warnings are?  A/B studies, before/after studies, or otherwise; do they have a significant impact on user behaviour?

An example use I noticed on German Language Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot of a tag warning]
<sup>Example from German Language SE</sup>

They seem to be used very little (I only became aware of them after 8 years and 243k rep on the network), so I suspect there may not be much data on their effectiveness.  Or maybe I happen to not try tags that have tag warnings attached to them ☺.

Comment: I guess they are quite _seen_ in [so], while in other sites are not put in place. From your profile I see you are active in other sites, so that may be the reason why you weren't aware of them so far.

Comment: What do you consider to be "effective"?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that you ask for moderators to be able to generate tag-warnings and then ask if these are even effective or not.

Comment: On Sports.SE they made autograph ID questions off-topic a little while ago, but kept the tag for legacy purposes, with a big caps-lock message in the tag description telling people those questions are now off-topic and not to use the tag. Nobody seems to pay any attention to it. I'm willing to bet it's the same with tag warnings.

Comment: @Tom We don't know if they're effective if we can't use them and try.

Comment: So this question makes no sense right now? Or why do you ask now, when you know it can't be answered?

Comment: @Tom Maybe they're in use on other sites.  Or maybe we can answer this question in the future.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I have no problem with these questions, I just wondered about the timing and order of them. I would have expected you ask first if they are efficient and after getting proof ask to broaden their usage, but no big deal.