# Can a badge be awarded for reading a post?

Tags: discussion, badges, asking-questions

First of all, my apologies if it has already been asked, but my initial research has lead to no results.

I haven't discussed with my Community first, because before asking them if they agree with the idea (whether is good or not), I want to know if it is "Stack-Exchange possible".

In Music Fans, we allow identification questions. Even it sometimes attracts poor questions, we try to have guidelines on what should be done to maximise the quality of an ID question, it is a Meta Question post: [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question)

New users, even if they have good will and read the tour, miss that post. My idea is to link that post to the tour, and award a bronze badge to the user.

This badge would also let us, active users and moderators, know that user read the post and have starting point of discussion on how to help them with their question.

Is that technically possible?

Comment: Your question reads like a feature request, which could mean that [**voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Glorfindel, and what feature am I asking? My first intention were not a feature request, AdamLear changed my question into a feature request, I let him do as I trusted him since he has a diamond. I didn't expect it to attract bullies.

Comment: I suspect that users interpret your question as 'Would it be a good idea to award a badge to users who read a certain post?' (to be honest, that isn't too far off), and three users don't think so and downvoted. (I upvoted, not because I think it's a good idea but because you're posing an interesting situation which deserves to be discussed.) You're not getting bullied, people here vote on post content, not on who wrote them. And Adam Lear changed it into a *discussion*, because [tag:support] is more for questions like 'I don't know how this feature of the site works, please help me out.'

Comment: I also suspect that if you'd written the question as 'I desperately want users who are asking a question about X on site Y to read a certain Q&A on Meta; what can I do about this?' and used the badge as an *example* solution, this question wouldn't receive three downvotes.

Comment: There is no badge awarded for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible with the current setup (but I guess you could make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for it). Let me offer you an alternative: use a [tag warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338875/295232).

[image]

This message is a little bit 'in your face' but I think it's exactly what is needed here. I suggest you post a question on [Music Fans' own meta site](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/) to collaborate with the community on the exact wording. The ♦ moderators can then make a request to the Community Manager to install the tag warning.

Comment: I'm really not comfortable with asking questions in Meta SE, but I'll think about it. Any way, this is a good idea, but I'll wait a little in case other ideas come. And of course, I'll will discuss it with my community.